# Why is my haar classifier slow?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

I trained a HAAR classifier to detect hands in a LIVE VIDEO FEED from the webcam.
I used 621 positives & 3712 negatives.

I used opencv_createsamples to generate the vec file for positives:
./opencv_createsamples -vec /Users/.../positivesvec.vec -info /Users/.../positiveDesc.txt -w 20 -h 30

And then, I used opencv_traincascade to train the classifier:
opencv_traincascade -data /Users/.../hand -vec /Users/.../positivesvec.vec -bg /Users/.../negativeDesc.txt -numPos 621 -numNeg 3712 -numStages 15 minHitRate 0.999 maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -w 20 -h 30 -mode ALL

The training took around 30 hours or so and I got an xml file. However, when I use that xml file for detection, it is really VERY slow (1 frame in 3-4 seconds maybe).

I know that my object detection code is correct because it works perfectly for faces. This is what I use:

```
trained_cascade_name = "/Users/.../cascade.xml";
if( !cascade.load( trained_cascade_name ) ){ qDebug()<<"Error loading cascade file!"; return; };
std::vector<Rect> hands;
    Mat frame_gray; // Haar works on grayscale images
    cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);

    cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, hands, 1.1, 3, 0|CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING|CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT, cv::Size(30,30),cv::Size(100,100));
    CvPoint topleft, bottomright;
    for( int i = 0; i < hands.size(); i++ )
      {
        topleft.x=hands[i].x;
        topleft.y=hands[i].y;
        bottomright.x=hands[i].x+hands[i].width;
        bottomright.y=hands[i].y+hands[i].height;
        cv::rectangle(frame, topleft, bottomright, Scalar(255,0,255), 1, 8, 0);
      }
```

Comment: are you search over the same size ranges for faces and hands?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with faces. I'm not sure what you mean. The variable name was "faces". I've changed that now, so that it doesn't cause confusion.

Comment: You say the algorithm is fast with faces but slow with hands. Are you passing the same size range  paramters to cascade.detectMultiScale()?

Comment: yes... it's the same.

Comment: perhaps you can use a similar method as this guy to lower the search region to increase speed: http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/eye-detection-and-tracking/

Answer (score 1):

For different objects different number of trees /stumps per stage are generated in order to reject 50% of false positives.

Pick any region and classify it. During this procedure check how many trees / stumps is invoked in lower stages.

Maybe your cascade just have more trees /stumps per stage so it spends more time to classify a region.

That is just a wild guess....

Answer (score 0):

You can set a higher value for scaleFactor, which you have as 1.1, if you set it higher it might run faster, but it will also miss some detections.